How can i display a map on Facebook that will show and update reports of incidents on the map?
This can be done the hard way but I am hoping someone could suggest some built-in meta/facebook functionality to achieve it more simply. Requirements:

Display a map of Victoria or all Australia with simple markers indicating incidents at different locations. Hovering or clicking on a marker displays further info.
Update the map based on reports from group members. this doesn't have to be automatic, we can have a member who is responsible for reports ending up on the map and some oversight is probably a good idea anyway.

Basically the same idea as a traffic, fire or weather warning map, just dealing with a different (and simpler) type of incident.
Thanks.
